# get type inside variant key object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to get the type of a variant object prop, but I don't know how to get that type so deeply.

Example:

```
interface Foo {
    name: string;
    id: string;
}

interface Bar {
    [key: string]: Foo;
}

interface Baz {
    source: number;
}

// The effect I want to reach
// type Bat =  Foo & Baz;

// But not using `Foo` and `Baz`, but `Bar` and `Baz`
type Bat = (Something with `Bar`) & Baz;
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Bar` is defined with an index signature of a `string`, you can use any `string` (eg: `"foo"`) or `string` itself.

```js
interface Foo {
  name: string;
  id: string;
}

interface Bar {
  [key: string]: Foo;
}

interface Baz {
  source: number;
}

type Bat = Bar[string] & Baz;

// Can also use an arbitary string, but this is less general
type BatAlernative = Bar["foo"] & Baz;

// Property 'source' is missing in type
const invalid: Bat = {
  name: "test",
  id: "42"
};

//  Property 'id' is missing in type
const invalid2: Bat = {
  name: "test",
  source: 3
};

const valid: Bat = {
  name: "test",
  id: "42",
  source: 3
};
```

This is similar to referencing the element types in an array using `number`.

```js
type Arr = Array<boolean | string>;
type ElementTypes = Arr[number];
```

This is a good overview for using index signatures: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures

Comment: Thank you very much!! I'll never get that is that simple!